# Discrete SeekBar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am trying to create a [discrete seek bar](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#sliders-discrete-slider) for an Android app.

[image: Example]

I know I can set max and min values for a `SeekBar` (my ideal solution would be the *Click* example below) but I want the bar to move up and down the slider at particular intervals - every 10 in my case. So the only options available on the `SeekBar` would be;

- 20
- 30
- 40
- 50
- 60
- 70

Is it possible to define specific values to a standard Android `SeekBar` or at least change the intervals between items. If not, then would it be possible with a custom seekbar? I have not found anything online which addresses this (not for Android at least - frustrating as its a recognised component in the Google Material design guidelines).

Comment: well if you are still looking for it then check [this](https://github.com/ankitgusai/IntervalSeekBar). i had similar requirement. i also needed the smooth scroll between the interval.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Check this link](http://nileshsenta.blogspot.in/2016/10/discrete-seekbar-without-third-party.html)
If you want to implement discrete seekbar with number of gaps without using third party library then use style property of seekbar.

```
<SeekBar
     android:id="@+id/sb"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:max="10"
     android:thumb="@drawable/ic_location"
     android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete" />
```

[image]

Comment: its very weird to see a thumb dragger at the middle not at the top

Comment: The link is not opening

Answer (score 6):

The Android `SeekBar` cannot set intervals, but you can set the maximum value to 10 so that the range is [0, 10], and whenever you want to get a value from it, multiply the `SeekBar`'s value by 10, so you can "simulate" having intervals of 0, 10, 20, 30, ...

Comment: I actually just found another example which also uses math to manipulate value. I guess this is how I will have to do it.